# how to customise Bottom Navigation bar item in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I need to design a Bottom Navigation bar...  Each tab item should consist of Text and an orange line .. If i use
BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
label: 'HOME',
activeIcon: Container(
color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0),
),
)
I get the orange line above the text.. May I know how to bring the orange line at the bottom of the tab... ?

[image]

[image]

```
        class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 45.0)
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 45.0)
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 45.0)
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 45.0)
              ]),
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 45.0)
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: CustomTabletAppBar(_scaffoldKey),
      body: WebViewContainer('http://www.google.com'),
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
          canvasColor: '#393939'.toColor(),
        ),
        child: CustomBottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can think BottomNavigationBarItem like a Column. icon and activeIcon are painted on top, it then draws label text below the icon. You can create your custom widgets and assign to `icon` and `activeIcon` properties, a simple Column for example. Then disable showing labels with setting false as  `showUnselectedLabels: false` and `showSelectedLabels: false` . Or there is a package called "persistent_bottom_nav_bar" which includes underlined icon option.

Comment: I tried BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('HOME'),
                ),
                Container(color: '#D86300'.toColor(), height: 5.0, width: 70.0)
              ]), but I am not getting the desired result

Comment: can you include full image of the ui?

Comment: @Suat Özkaya Thanks... your suggestion helped me.... to fix the problem....